# How do I count records that satisfy a condition in a associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

Okay, what I've got is two models...

Jiraissue:

```
class Jiraissue < ActiveRecord::Base
  # JIRA uses a singular table name for this model
  set_table_name 'jiraissue'
  has_one :severity
end
```

Severity:

```
class Severity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :jiraissue
end
```

What I'm trying to do is get a count of all Jiraissues for which jiraissue.severity = "S1"

Now it turns out that the jiraissue table has a column for priority so I can pull this trick in the model...

Jiraissue:

```
class Jiraissue < ActiveRecord::Base
  # JIRA uses a singular table name for this model
  set_table_name 'jiraissue'
  has_one :severity

  def self.count_priority(priority)
    where("PRIORITY = ?",priority).count()
  end

end
```

And then in the view do something like...

```
<%= (1..4).map {
  |priority| Jiraissue.biit.bugs.recent.count_priority(priority)
  }.inspect %>
```

How do I do something similar for Jiraissue to get a count_severity method?

This just doesn't work (nor would I expect it to)...

```
  def self.count_severity(severity)
    where("severity = ?",severity).count()
  end
```

But I'm totally confused.

Comment: Me too totally confused ;)... ` jiraissue.severity` will return an association object of `Severity` class right? How do you compare `jiraissue.severity = "S1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Jiraissue.joins(:severities).where(:severities => {:severity => "S1"}).count
```

Comment: Hooray!!

Jiraissue.joins(:severity).where(:severities => {:severity => "S1"}).count

This TOTALLY works!  Thanks for getting me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

**model**

```
def self.count_priority(priority)
  where("PRIORITY = ?",priority).size
end
```

**controller**

```
def index
  @jiraissues = Jiraissue.count_priority('S1')
end
```

Doesn't it work?

Comment: Nope, that won't work because priority is not a column in the jiraissue table.  I'm thinking bdon's answer might be just what I'm looking for.